# How to Create JButton Array with Loops

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have three different files where I need to create an instance JButton array of size 10 for each, but using a "while" loop for the first file, a "do while" loop for the second, and a "for" loop for the third file. I can only use one "while" loop, one " do while" loop, and one "for" loop and I am confused on how to do this. Here's what I have so far, I am a beginner so I don't have much.

First file using "while" loop:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WhileLoopButton extends JFrame {

    public WhileLoopButton() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("Button Array");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new WhileLoopButton();
    }
}
```

Second file using "do while" loop

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DoWhileLoopButton extends JFrame {

    public DoWhileLoopButton() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("Button Array");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new DoWhileLoopButton();
    }
}
```

Third file using "for" loop

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ForLoopButton extends JFrame {

    public ForLoopButton() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("Button Array");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ForLoopButton();
    }
}
```